# Is there a way I can associate an Edge Chromium profile to a specific virtual desktop in Windows 10?

Tags: microsoft-edge, virtual-desktop, productivity, task-switching

I'm a consultant running multiple projects concurrently. I use virtual desktops for each project, and have multiple Edge Chromium user profiles.

How can I associate these profiles with a virtual desktop? Say click on Edge shortcut in VD2 and get profile 2?

Comment: If a virtual desktop can have shortcuts then you can create unique shortcuts for Edge that point to specific Edge (Chrome) profiles using the appropriate shortcut flags.  Have you tried that?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to superuser.com Marc.

[VDesk](https://github.com/eksime/VDesk) (download and install [VDeskSetup.msi](https://github.com/eksime/VDesk/releases)) can switch to a desktop number and run a command there. You could create a shortcut to **vdesk.exe** for each project, open its properties, and edit the **Target** command.  For example (your paths may vary):

```
C:\Programs\VDesk\vdesk.exe  on:2  run:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe"  --profile-directory="Profile 2"
```

If you create the shortcuts in a folder, then you can add that folder to the Windows taskbar as a custom toolbar menu (**Taskbar > Toolbars > New toolbar... > [Select Folder]**).  Selecting an item from that menu will switch to the specified desktop and start Edge with the specified profile.

There are lots of tutorials on custom toolbar menus.  I like these for quick start and fiddly details:

- https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/67619-add-toolbars-taskbar-windows-10-a.html#option4
- https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/67619-add-toolbars-taskbar-windows-10-a-3.html